# How to find difference in minute between two column in Oracle where both column datatype is timestamp?

Tags: database, oracle10g

How to find difference in minute between two column in Oracle where both column datatype is timestamp?

I need alternative solution for oracle database for below postgres query.

This query is working in postgresql .

```
select 
    time_stamp, read_time, 
    round(extract(epoch from (time_stamp - read_time))/60) 
from 
    tablename
```

`time_stamp` and `read_time` are two columns.

Answer (score 1):

**Test data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, value1, value2 ) AS
  SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2019-09-30 00:00:00.000', TIMESTAMP '2019-09-30 00:05:00.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2019-09-30 00:00:00.100', TIMESTAMP '2019-09-30 00:05:00.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, TIMESTAMP '2019-09-30 00:00:00.000', TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 00:05:00.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, TIMESTAMP '2019-09-30 00:00:00.001', TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 00:05:00.000' FROM DUAL;
```

This has differences of 5 minutes, 5 minutes minus a few microseconds, 1 day and 1 day minus a microsecond.

**Query**:

If you just naively use `DATE` (by using either `CAST( value AS DATE)` or `TRUNC( value, 'SS' )`) then you will get the wrong value as it will ignore any fractional seconds in your `TIMESTAMP`s; instead you can find the difference between the `TIMESTAMP`s `TRUNC`ated to the nearest minute (using `TRUNC` will involve an implicit `CAST` to a `DATE` data type) and then add the difference between the `SECOND` components:

```sql
SELECT id,
       ROUND(
         ( TRUNC( value2, 'MI' ) - TRUNC( value1, 'MI' ) ) * 24 * 60
           + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM value2 ) / 60
           - EXTRACT( SECOND FROM value1 ) / 60,
         7
       ) AS time_difference_in_minutes
FROM   test_data;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | TIME_DIFFERENCE_IN_MINUTES
> -: | -------------------------:
>  1 |                          5
>  2 |                  4.9983333
>  3 |                       1440
>  4 |               1439.9999833
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1078f93ca2b2fe095abde7af4ca2339d)*

Answer (score 0):

When subtracting two date values (which also contain a time component, hours/minutes/seconds - if that's what you call a "timestamp" - I believe you do), then the result is **number of days** between them. That's why you have to compute number of minutes by multiplying days with 24 (as there are 24 hours in a day) and 60 (as there are 60 minutes in an hour).

For example:

```
SQL> create table test (a date, b date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values
  2    (to_date('30.09.2019 07:56', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
  3     to_date('30.09.2019 08:14', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
  4    );

1 row created.

SQL> select
  2    b - a days,
  3    (b - a) * 24 hours,
  4    (b - a) * (24 * 60) minutes
  5  from test;

      DAYS      HOURS    MINUTES
---------- ---------- ----------
     ,0125         ,3         18

SQL>
```

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is a specific data type that has fractional seconds; it is not the same as a `DATE` (but you can `CAST` from one to the other). If you subtract one `TIMESTAMP` from another you do not get the number of days but an `INTERVAL` data type instead.

Comment: I know, @MT0. I also know that people rather often say "timestamp" when they mean "date". That's why I *simplified* it as the question talks about "difference in minutes", and I hope I'm not wrong. Apart from that, I agree with you & will upvote your answer.